Facing fatal error while linking cpp code with assembly code
I am trying to assemble a small piece of assembly code using MASM and then link it with a C++ program. Here is the assembly code:
    .code

    option casemap:none

    public asmFunc

asmFunc PROC
    ret ;
asmFunc ENDP
        END

And here is the cpp code:
#include <stdio.h>


extern "C" {
    void asmFunc(void);
}

int main() {
    printf("Calling asm main!");
    asmFunc();
    printf("Returned from asm!");
    return 0;
}

Then I successfully assembled the assembly code using ml64 /c first.asm. A .obj file was created.
Then I expected that I can easily link the code using cl first.cpp first.asm but unfortunately I ran into this error:

C:\Users\jarzi\Videos\Programs\c programs\assem1>cl first.cpp first.asm          
Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.00.24215.1 для x64
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation).  Все права защищены.

cl: командная строка warning D9024: нераспознанный тип исходных файлов "first.asm", использование объектного файла
first.cpp
first.cpp(1): fatal error C1034: stdio.h: не указан путь поиска включаемых файлов



You should probably post this at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ instead?

I have no idea what the error message tells you, but if you get an error already for including stdio.h your installation of the compiler seems to be broken. Can you build a program if you don't include asm files?

Please change your locale to English, so compiler will report error in form acceptable by other users.

I do not think that cl is a linker.  Even if it was a linker, it certainly would not link source files, let alone .cpp and .asm source files.  You need to go back and start reading the basics.

A linker does not link code, it links object files.
In principle, you need to do the following:

Invoke your assembler to assemble your .asm file into an .obj file
Invoke your compiler to compile your .cpp file into another .obj file
Invoke your linker to link the two .obj files together and produce an executable.

Now, the cl command of the Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler mixes the capabilities of both a compiler and a linker, so you may be able to skip one of the above steps, but in order to use it, you need to be aware of the following:

You can use cl to compile .cpp files, but you cannot use it to assemble .asm files.   (Source)  You have to use ml for that, and then give cl the resulting .obj file.

You better give your source files different names, otherwise your first.cpp will yield first.obj, and then your first.asm will also yield first.obj, so the second first.obj will overwrite the first first.obj, so there will never be two separate .obj files to link.



Are you sure about the last paragraph with creating two first.obj files if you're telling the compiler to create a .exe?  With GCC or clang, if you don't use -c to stop at object files, they compile or assemble into .o files with unique names in /tmp unless you use -save-temps, so you can indeed do g++ foo.c foo.cpp foo.cc foo.S -o foo with no problem.  At no point would GCC ever create a foo.o in this directory.  Of course MSVC could be different.

While this might be true, it doesn't address the error OP is actually getting; which is complaining about stdio.h not existing.

@PeterCordes no, I am not sure about it.  But I would certainly fix that before I was to try anything else.

@ChrisMM the OP uses ml64 to assemble an .asm file into an .obj file, then goes on to completely ignore that .obj file and is trying to feed cl with the .asm file, and then the OP is showing us error messages in Russian.  Under these circumstances, my course of action is the only one that I believe makes sense, which is to tell them to get the obvious things right.  Their weird unidentifiable problem is likely to go away as a result.

@ChrisMM and if they do things right and their weird unidentifiable problem persists, then I will get to it.  But first things first, and one thing at a time.

"First things first" is to get past the error they're getting ... If they fix what you suggest, they still have exactly the same error.
